# Filling 22 TComboBoxes taking over 4 seconds

Tags: delphi

Our application is written in Delphi XE7 on a Windows 10 computer.. We have 26 TComboBox's on a Form. When we read from a file and fill these ComboBox lists it is taking over 4 seconds. The maximum size of the list box is around 800 items. This seems a little long to fill list boxes. We are writing to text file to see how long it takes. The Debuginfo procedure writes the information to the text file. Here are the results:

- 22:11:10.179, Start Fill Digital List
- 22:11:10.180, Start Clear Digital List
- 22:11:10.182, End Clear Digital List
- 22:11:10.183, Start Parse Digital List
- 22:11:10.536, End Parse Digital List
- 22:11:10.536, Start Copy Digital List
- 22:11:15.667, End Copy Digital List
- 22:11:15.668, End Fill Digital List

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Our code is below:

```
procedure TForm1.fill_digital_lists(whserch:string; dg:byte);
var xdr:integer; filltxt:string;
begin
  with work_cfg do
  begin
    debuginfo(wavepath,formatdatetime('hh:nn:ss.zzz',now)+', Start Fill Digital List');
    if totdig>0 then
    begin
      debuginfo(wavepath,formatdatetime('hh:nn:ss.zzz',now)+', Start Clear Digital List');
      brk1.Items.Clear;
      brk2.Items.Clear;
      brk3.Items.Clear;
      brk4.Items.Clear;
      evt1.Items.Clear;
      evt2.Items.Clear;
      evt3.Items.Clear;
      evt4.Items.Clear;
      evt5.Items.Clear;
      evt6.Items.Clear;
      evt7.Items.Clear;
      evt8.Items.Clear;
      evt9.Items.Clear;
      evt10.Items.Clear;
      evt11.Items.Clear;
      evt12.Items.Clear;
      evt13.Items.Clear;
      evt14.Items.Clear;
      evt15.Items.Clear;
      evt16.Items.Clear;
      evt17.Items.Clear;
      evt18.Items.Clear;
      evt19.Items.Clear;
      evt20.Items.Clear;
      evt21.Items.Clear;
      evt22.Items.Clear;
      debuginfo(wavepath,formatdatetime('hh:nn:ss.zzz',now)+', End Clear Digital List');
      debuginfo(wavepath,formatdatetime('hh:nn:ss.zzz',now)+', Start Parse Digital List');
      for xdr:=1 to totdig do
      begin
        if ansipos('SPARE',ansiuppercase(digitl_chans[xdr]))=0 then
        begin
          filltxt:='';
          if (dg=1) and (length(whserch)>0) then
          begin
            if (ansipos(ansiuppercase(whserch),ansiuppercase(digitl_chans[xdr]))>0) then filltxt:=digitl_chans[xdr]
          end else filltxt:=digitl_chans[xdr];
          if length(filltxt)>0 then brk1.Items.Add(filltxt);
        end;
      end;
      debuginfo(wavepath,formatdatetime('hh:nn:ss.zzz',now)+', End Parse Digital List');
      debuginfo(wavepath,formatdatetime('hh:nn:ss.zzz',now)+', Start Copy Digital List');
      brk2.Items:=brk1.Items;
      brk3.Items:=brk1.Items;
      brk4.Items:=brk1.Items;
      evt1.Items:=brk1.Items;
      evt2.Items:=brk1.Items;
      evt3.Items:=brk1.Items;
      evt4.Items:=brk1.Items;
      evt5.Items:=brk1.Items;
      evt6.Items:=brk1.Items;
      evt7.Items:=brk1.Items;
      evt8.Items:=brk1.Items;
      evt9.Items:=brk1.Items;
      evt10.Items:=brk1.Items;
      evt11.Items:=brk1.Items;
      evt12.Items:=brk1.Items;
      evt13.Items:=brk1.Items;
      evt14.Items:=brk1.Items;
      evt15.Items:=brk1.Items;
      evt16.Items:=brk1.Items;
      evt17.Items:=brk1.Items;
      evt18.Items:=brk1.Items;
      evt19.Items:=brk1.Items;
      evt20.Items:=brk1.Items;
      evt21.Items:=brk1.Items;
      evt22.Items:=brk1.Items;
      debuginfo(wavepath,formatdatetime('hh:nn:ss.zzz',now)+', End Copy Digital List');
    end;
    debuginfo(wavepath,formatdatetime('hh:nn:ss.zzz',now)+', End Fill Digital List');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You don't use ```BeginUpdate``` and ```EndUpdate``` of the comboboxes' ```Items``` property! This should drastically decrease the needed amount of time to fill all the comboboxes!

Comment: Any time you need to access a bunch of variables sequentially, it is a good idea to put them into an array and loop over that instead. Doing so will drastically simplify this code.

Comment: Accessing the brk1.Items property always gets the TStrings from the underlying Windows control. One simple optimization would be to create the list as a local TStringList and then assign it to all the comboboxes. No idea how much that would affect the timing, but it should improve it.

Comment: `ansiuppercase(whserch)` (and `ansiuppercase(digitl_chans[xdr])`) is unnecessarily done multiple times when you could do it once and then use a variable.

Answer (score -1):

You do unnecessary items changes and spend some time for drawing. I made small optimizations into your code.Try to do like this:

```
procedure TForm1.fill_digital_lists(whserch:string; dg:byte);
var
  xdr : integer;
  filltxt : string;
  strList : TStringList;
  i : integer;

  procedure ProcessComboboxes(const AStartOfName : string; const MaxIndex : integer);
  var
    i : integer;
    cmp : TComponent;
  begin
    for i := 1 to MaxIndex do
    begin
      cmp := Self.FindComponent(AStartOfName + i.ToString);
      if Assigned(cmp) and (cmp is TComboBox) then
         //this will clear origin items and set new
         (cmp as TComboBox).Items.SetStrings(strList);
    end;
  end;

begin
  with work_cfg do
  begin
    debuginfo(wavepath,formatdatetime('hh:nn:ss.zzz',now)+', Start Fill Digital List');
    if totdig > 0 then
    begin
      debuginfo(wavepath,formatdatetime('hh:nn:ss.zzz',now)+', Start Parse Digital List');
      strList := TStringlist.Create;
      try
        strList.BeginUpdate;
        for xdr := 1 to totdig do
        begin
          if ansipos('SPARE',ansiuppercase(digitl_chans[xdr]))=0 then
          begin
            filltxt:='';
            if (dg = 1) and (length(whserch)>0) then
            begin
              if (ansipos(ansiuppercase(whserch), ansiuppercase(digitl_chans[xdr]))>0) then
                filltxt := digitl_chans[xdr]
            end else
              filltxt := digitl_chans[xdr];
            if length(filltxt) > 0 then
              strList.Add(filltxt);
          end;
        end;
        strList.EndUpdate;

        debuginfo(wavepath,formatdatetime('hh:nn:ss.zzz',now)+', End Parse Digital List');

        debuginfo(wavepath,formatdatetime('hh:nn:ss.zzz',now)+', Start Copy Digital List');
        //lock drawing of our form
        LockWindowUpdate(self.Handle);
        try
          ProcessComboboxes('brk', 4);
          ProcessComboboxes('evt', 22);
        finally
          //restore drawing of our form
          LockWindowUpdate(0);
        end;
        debuginfo(wavepath,formatdatetime('hh:nn:ss.zzz',now)+', End Copy Digital List');
      finally
        strList.Free;
      end;
    end;
    debuginfo(wavepath,formatdatetime('hh:nn:ss.zzz',now)+', End Fill Digital List');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: (1) If you use `FindComponent`, you are doing it wrong. (2) You absolutely MUST protect `BeginUpdate`...`EndUpdate` with a `try..finally`. (3) A long, top-level `with` is dangerous. (4) [`LockWindowUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-lockwindowupdate) is not the right function to use. Instead, you should use `WM_SETREDRAW` or Embarcadero's brand new VCL wrapper. (5) `Assigned(cmp) and (cmp is TComboBox)` is exactly equal to `cmp is TComboBox` because `nil` doesn't point to a `TComboBox` instance.

Comment: Andreas Rejbrand. (1) He does not have any array of comboboxes, so FindComponent is simple way to write less code without changing anything else. (2)I agree for generic solution, but in this code it's not necessery coz it's for local variable. (3) It's part of origin code, i don't know what variables he use from this part so must leave as it is. (4) He can't use new VCL wrapper, coz write in XE7. (5) Agree, but it's not critical.

Comment: 2) is not about memory leak protection, but proper handling of two related commands!

Comment: "*`LockWindowUpdate` is not the right function to use. Instead, you should use `WM_SETREDRAW` or Embarcadero's brand new VCL wrapper*" - `Items.(Begin|End)Update()` use `WM_SETREDRAW` internally.

Comment: @OleksandrMorozevych using `FindComponent()` is going to significantly slow down the code even more, since it is a dynamic lookup using string comparisons. At least the original code was accessing the target components directly, thus no lookup.  Putting those same components into an array instead would avoid the need for `FindComponent()` without degrading performance, while cutting the code size in half

Comment: Hello Everyone,

Comment: Hello Everyone. Thanks for the replies. Oleksandr, we tried your code and our XE7 does not support the SetStrings method inside Tstrings. Must have been added at a later version. We changed it to Items:=strList. It is now taking around 3 seconds. A little better but not great. Is it worth it to move the Tcomboboxes to an array if there is no improvement in speed. We tried the SendMessage(Handle,WM_SETREDRAW,0,0); before updating the comboboxes and SendMessage(Handle,WM_SETREDRAW,1,0); after. Not much change. What if we disable all the Comboboxes before updating then enable after updating.

Comment: @MRoth the most useful help in this topic is in the comments immediately below your question

Comment: @MRoth Right way to solve it IMHO: redesign GUI and split comboboxes into some parts (for example TabSheets of Page control). When you do parsing save result into some cache variable. When user need to see comboboxes – load items only into visible comboboxes (for example in OnTabChange event or OnEnter combobox Event). Total spend time will be same or even more, but user will not notice it, coz it will be spitted in few lower pars of time + parsing of file can be putted into separated thread.

Comment: @MRoth I wrote this sources in 10.4.2. Put all comboboxes in array would help if you got lot of component on form (speed of FindComponent depends from size of collection Components). It will be faster anyway, but maybe for few milliseconds. Items:=strList in 10.4.2 already do internally BeginUpdate/EndUpdate internally, so do it manually one more time would not help too (better to check it in your version)

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your comments. We decided to go with the beginupdate and endupdate. We tested each option (beginupdate, WM_SETREDRAW and LockWindowUpdate) and they all performed about the same. Around 2 to 3 seconds to fill the 26 Tcomboboxes.

Comment: This still sounds way too long!

Comment: @DelphiCoder It's not too long if all those TCombobox'es have 800 items inside. But @ MRoth... a TCombobox with 800 items is just bad design. How is a user going to pick an item from a list of 800? It's better to design something dynamic in that case (autosuggest with the letters already typed).